# how to place every text in record at the left side of the label?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter, widget

```
print_records = '''
    for record in records:
        print_records += str(record[0]) + "          " + str(record[1]) + "          " + str(record[2]) \
                         + "          " + str(record[3]) + "          " + str(record[4]) + "          " + str(record[5]) \
                         + "          " + str(record[6]) + "          " + str(record[7]) + "\n"

        show = Label(root, width=120,  text=print_records, anchor=NW)
        show.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        show.place(x=402, y=50, height=510)
        show.config(font=("TimesNewRoman", 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `justify="left"` in `Label(...)`.